# Ellipses for selected individuals - Factoextra plots

Tags: r, plot, pca, ellipse, factoextra

In order to show specific features from the results of my PCA (with FactomineR), I am trying to manipulate the plot of individuals and the biplot with the factoextra package.

I want to draw ellipses around my individuals, but they belong to 10 different groups and the result is not easily readable, so I would like to **select the more representative groups for drawing ellipses, while keeping all the individuals represented on the graphs** (as dots + names).

So far, I haven't succeed in keeping both (individuals with ellipse + individuals without) trying this kind of things

```
fviz_ellipses(res.pca, select.list= list(name= "active.ind"),  habillage = DF$Group, addEllipses = T)
```

with `active.ind` a vector of the selected rows (individuals).

I tried adding ellipses like a geom in ggplot2, like this

```
fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, repel = T)+
fviz_ellipses(res.pca, select.list= list(name= "active.ind"),  habillage = DF$Group, addEllipses = T)
```

but it returns the error `Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot`

I am also wondering if there is any way to **separate the colours of the individuals and the ellipses, having colours matching a group and ellipses matching another** (there would be a coloured circle ellipse grouping dots of different colour): `habillage` and `addEllipses` seem to always work together, but is there any other way to add a scale_color or something like that and make it prevail over `habillage` ?

The easier thing I could think of would be to add ellipses as an independent object, although I have no clue about how to do that.

Any thoughts would be very welcome. Thanks !